# how to change .apk namespace

Tags: android, apk

I want to find a way to change an .apk's namespace without having to fiddle with it at the source level.  I know I can copy a project in eclipse and change the namespace that way but I don't want to go to all that trouble.  I may want to have dozens of apks that are the same program all with unique namespaces.

Why do I want to do this?  I have my reasons.

EDIT...
After reading initial responses, maybe it would help if I state my reason.  I want to have ten versions of my app on Google Play all with different app names but I don't want to have 10 eclipse projects each with a different namespace.  The ten apps will all install on the phone under the same name - just the name in the store listing is different and maybe a different icon in the store listing.  Google Play requires me to have a unique namespace for each of the ten apps.

This is all because Google Play does not allow keywords to be provided other than the name of the app.  I have five apps on Google Play but they are virtually hidden.  No one can find them.
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Note that relatively little of your code actually needs to be in a java namespace matching the APK package name.  For that which does, automated renaming in a script is possible - you'll need to change both directory names and some file contents.  `sed` is a nice scriptable tool for the later.  Technically you could do this with later stage files containing dalvik code, included decompilations which can be rebuilt.

Comment: You may want to look at the "free and paid versions of the same app" type questions, as the requirement for different package names there is basically the same requirement you face.

Comment: with android studio I think you can define different namespace for each "flavor" or build type.